# React: How to pass state to child component and call function in child to use this state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am implementing a component in functional components where there are several other child components in it passing data to each other. I need to pass data from parent to child component and call some function there to use it.
In class componenets we use **componentdidupdate** but could not understand how to do in functional component.

One idea is to use **useEffect** hook but could not do with it.

Comment: Please provide some code to show what you have tried, so we can try help with context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im going to take a stab here, because we dont have context or code to go with.

useEffect accepts a dependency array to which it will react when a value or object reference changes

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {

  const {
    valuePassedFromParent
  } = props;

  const actionFunction = (value) => {
     //perform some tasks with value passed from parent when it changes
 }

  //this is similar to componentDidUpdate, but it reacts to changes in valuePassedFromParent though props since its in the useEffect dependency array
  useEffect(() => {    
    //do something with valuePassedFromParent
    actionFunction(valuePassedFromParent);
  },[valuePassedFromParent]);


  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: Can you help me out for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176305/changing-props-state-using-api-causes-infinite-loop

Answer (score 0):

You cas use `useEffect` to reproduce the behavior of `componentdidupdate` like this :

```
const [myState,setMyState] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
   ...
},[myState]);
```

The function use effect will run every time `myState` will be updated, like `componentdiduptate` would have do.

In your case, the state is given by the parent component if I understand well, so just replace the `myState` in the array dependency by the state given through the prop of your child component.