# Changing props state using api causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I don't know why, changing the props state inside useEffect causes infinite loop of errors. I used them first locally declaring within the function without using props which was running ok.

**EDIT:**

Home.js

```
import Axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Home(props) {
  // const [details, setDetails] = useState({});
  // const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const data = localStorage.getItem("expensesAccDetails");
      if (data) {
        Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/eachCollectionData", {
          collection: data,
        }).then((res) => {
          if (res.data.err) {
            console.log("Error");
          } else {
            console.log(res.data[0]);
            props.setLogin(true);
            props.setUserdetails(res.data[0]);
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);

  return props.login ? (
    <div>
      <div>Welcome {props.setUserdetails.FullName}</div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>You need to login first</div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);
  const [userdetails, setUserdetails] = useState({});

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/Home"
          element={
            <>
              <Home
                setLogin={setLogin}
                login={login}
                setUserdetails={setUserdetails}
                userdetails={userdetails}
              />
              <Bars login={login} />
            </>
          }
        />
      <Routes>
    <Router>

  );
```

Here I initialized the states directly in App.js so I don't have to declare it on every page for the route renders. I just passed them as props to every component.

Comment: can you post how this component is used??

Comment: @FelipeRodriguezHerrera you can check it now! The updated code, tell me if you want any other code, I just need to get this thing cleared

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create a componente Home with the post and two sub-component inside:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({});
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // api call
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Welcome login={login} details={userDetails} />
      <Bars login={login} details={userDetails} />
    </>
  );
};
```

where Welcome is the following:

```
const Welcome = ({ userdetails, login }) => (
  <>
    login ? (
    <div>
      <div>Welcome {userdetails.FullName}</div>
    </div>
    ) : (
    <div>You need to login first</div>
    );
  </>
);
```

A better solution is to use only one state variable:

```
const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState(null);
```

and test if userDetails is null as you test login is true.

An alternative if you have to maintain the call as you write before, you can use two state as the follow:

```
function App() {
  const [userdetails, setUserdetails] = useState(null);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/Home"
          element={
            <>
              <Home
                setUserdetails={setUserdetails}
              />
              <Bars login={!!userdetails} />
            </>
          }
        />
      <Routes>
    <Router>
  );
```

and on Home component use a local state:

```
const Home = ({setUserdetails}) => {
  const [userDetailsLocal, setUserDetailsLocal] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // api call
    // ... on response received:
    setUserdetails(res.data[0]);
    setUserDetailsLocal(res.data[0]);
    // ...

  }, []);

  userDetailsLocal ? (
    <div>
       <div>Welcome {userDetailsLocal.FullName}</div>
    </div>
  ) : (
     <div>You need to login first</div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot do that as I have a total of 7 components each as a child of route tag and your solution will make it too much lengthy for me. Can you give a solution for change the state of props without causing a loop, Thanks : )

Comment: I aslo tried to call to call the api in the App.js and pass props to elements but I guess App.js doesn't render on each page render ?

Comment: yes is not a good idea to call api on App component if you don't want to call it on every route. My solution wants to isolate the call on common router parent as it should be. An other solution, but is not very elegant, is to duplicate state on App and inside Home: in this case you can not passing state tu Home, but only sets methods

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Comment: I've tried to explain better on my response

Comment: Thank you for the edit but the issue remains constant  : (

Answer (score 0):

I advise to follow Max arquitecture for your solution. the problem lies in the Router behavior. React Router is not part of React core, so you must use it outside your react logic.

from documentation of React Router:

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would create a new component every render.

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component

**Edit:**
ok, you make me write it. A solution could be like:

```
function App() {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);
  const [userdetails, setUserdetails] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const data = localStorage.getItem("expensesAccDetails");
      if (data) {
        Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/eachCollectionData", {
          collection: data,
        }).then((res) => {
          if (res.data.err) {
            console.log("Error");
          } else {
            console.log(res.data[0]);
            setLogin(true);
            setUserdetails(res.data[0]);
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/Home"
          element={
            <>
              <Home
                login={login}
                userdetails={userdetails}
              />
              <Bars login={login} />
            </>
          }
        />
      <Routes>
    <Router>

  );
```

Comment: I browsed pretty much on the internet and got to know to use React.memo() to avoid loops but it didn't work as well

Comment: I tried calling the api in App.js but it wont render on every route so the api call expires returning false value to the component.

Comment: But doesn't render infinite loop, so the initial problem you ask has been resolved.

Comment: If that would be the solution, I wouldn't had asked the question at first place : ]